# Matlab ODE45 weird artefacts in output

Tags: python, matlab, ode, numerical-integration

I have algorithm Implemented in Python and Matlab. It works ok in Python, but in Matlab I am getting weird artefacts in output (most of time, but not allways). See following image, the artefact is that high peak.

[image]

I tried to overcome all differences. I overwrite in Python all functions that differs from Matlab (for example division remainder). Maybe I miss something, but I do not think so. Output of functions seem to be consistent with all tests I figured out.

Only part I did not "normalize" is the ODE solver. In Matlab I use ode45 with defined array of time points.  In Python I use my own ODE45 and it works great, with no artefacts. I also tried different Python ode solvers (from scipy) and it works also great.

So my question is - do you know about any reason why Matlab (most probably the ode45) can cause such a weird errors sometimes?

Equations in matlab:

```
function dxdt = derivsecgsyn(t,x,flag,rr,sfint,ti,ai,bi)

xi = cos(ti);
yi = sin(ti);
ta = atan2(x(2),x(1));
r0 = 1;
a0 = 1.0 - sqrt(x(1)^2 + x(2)^2)/r0;
ip = 1+floor(t*sfint); 
w0 = 2*pi/rr(ip);


fresp = 0.25;
zbase = 0.005*sin(2*pi*fresp*t);

dx1dt = a0*x(1) - w0*x(2);
dx2dt = a0*x(2) + w0*x(1);

dti = rem(ta - ti, 2*pi);
dx3dt = - sum(ai.*dti.*exp(-0.5*(dti./bi).^2)) - 1.0*(x(3) - zbase);

dxdt = [dx1dt; dx2dt; dx3dt];
```

Comment: How discontinuous is your equation? Integer division hints at jump discontinuities which in general make already the existence of solutions questionable.

Comment: @LutzL Thank for comment. I attached Matlab function for equations. In Python it is ok, so it should be solveable.

Comment: Try to use smaller error tolerances. With the atan2, floor and rem operations you have several sources for jump discontinuities. Adaptive step-size regulators fail at such places and have to use heuristic work-arounds that will lead to (more than usual) random integration errors. With smaller tolerances, the algorithm will try harder and catch the jump locations more precisely. Or give a definitive error.